# Want to Show random products in Particular category in Home page, I got a code but product price will be repeat to all products, What to do?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I want to show `random products` in `particular category` in my home page, i tried this code http://www.magikcommerce.com/…/random-products-magento-hom…/ It working, but product price have extra 4 digits like : `1900.0000` how to remove last 4 digits can you help me ?

I tried magento default price module it remove last 4 digits, But it repeat single price to all products.

My working website : http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/ Please reply me as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation, I got a solution. Thanks Magento.stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace  from `$displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getPrice()` to `Mage::helper('core')->currency($displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getPrice(), true, false);`

Comment: @Vijayakumar can you please tell me reason for accepting another answer while   i have answer it first by using your code. anyway I glad to hear that my code is working :)

Comment: Sorry for that, i tried Qaisar Satti given codes and your codes, But your code give the result as i expected, But i got your code last 10 min ago. If i got your at earlier i can fix that bug earlier. Anyway Thanks for that.

Comment: @Vijayakumar if you talking about time then you can see my answer time and his comment time any way thanks for your time